# How do I modify "fewer"?

Tags: comparisons

In a sentence using *fewer* as a comparison between the present time and other occurrences, I might want to adjust the comparison. Are there any rules about how to modify *fewer*? Does it vary if the number is now larger ("less few") or smaller ("more few")?

> There are
>
> - any fewer
> - much fewer
> - little fewer
> - a lot of fewer
>
> people in the street than usual.

Comment: I've made this into an ELU question about ***how*** and ***why*** rather than a simple "What's the answer". There may still be duplicates and the community may still feel that it should show evidence of research. If you are learning English and need a more didactic approach to Q&A, please consider our sister site [ELL.SE].

Answer (score 1):

One commonly used qualifier is *even fewer* to describe a further decrease since the previous comparison. I am not aware of a common phrase to describe a movement in the opposite direction.